# Killing TCP connection on Windows via cmd prompt

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, tcp

There are already at least two similar threads on SU both having either outdated answers or answers that suggest using GUI.

Thus the following programs are **NOT** what I'm looking for:

- wkillcx - that looked like the right option but unfortunatelly it doesn't work either locally (WinServer 2008 and it's even worse via telnet - it shows only first line of the stdout and repeats it 3 times). It's written in assembly so it's even difficult for me to look into, perhaps the server is running not the processor that author assumed it will be running?
- tcpview (sysinternals) - this requires GUI, the cmdline part of tcpviewcon does not support killing connections
- CurrPorts - this program claims to support cli but what it actually does is it runs GUI part with arguments (i.e. you can start GUI with some filters), I don't see how that's "supporting cli" - again, it wont work via telnet
- kill the PID! -- No!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5453/Enhance-netstat The only difficulty was that I had to compile it in Visual Studio 6.0 (and I liked it. I was navigating through project settings way faster than in VS2013).